# How to define `health` and `maxHealth` in one object, when `healt` can't be higher than `maxHealth`?

Tags: c++, constructor, definition

I have a class called `Warrior` that has `uint m_health` and `uint m_maxHealth` attributes.
I want my constructor to take parameters `Warrior(uint health, uint maxHealth)`.

Now I've studied C++ a lot and I know all the syntax etc, but it's hard to find tutorials on how to use the stuff etc. so I don't really know how should I define `health` and `maxHealth` when `health` obviously can't be higher than `maxHealth` :/

Here are few methods I thought of:

```
// method 1
Warrior::Warrior(uint health, uint maxHealth) :
    m_health((health > maxHealth) ? maxHealth : health),
    m_maxHealth(maxHealth)
{}

// method 2
Warrior::Warrior(uint health, uint maxHealth) :
    m_maxHealth(maxHealth)
{
    if (health > maxHealth) {
        m_health = maxHealth;
    }
    else {
        m_health = health;
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are other ways too.
Sorry if this is just an opinion question, but if there's a "preferred" way in C++, what would it be?

Comment: Use [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)?

Comment: *Now I've studied C++ alot*, and yet probably not enough. I have spent years studying and I still learn every day.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas He never says he has learned enough? He even mentions that he still doesn't know how to use the stuff he has learned so far. It's such a good thing quoting a small part of someone's words, leaving the essential stuff out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just put an assertion or throw exception in case precondition is not met:

```
Warrior::Warrior(uint health, uint maxHealth) :
    m_health(health),
    m_maxHealth(maxHealth)
{
    assert(health <= maxHealth); 
    // or throw exception
    throw std::logic_error("explanation");
}
```

I mean, what is the rational to decide for the caller which value to take? If caller puts health value bigger than maxHealth - it's violation of your class logic, so I would propose to fail immediately and inform caller about this. It should be problem in the software, so I think it's not desirable to hide it.

Exception or assertion is an explicit mechanism that will help you to find and recognise such problems early.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is fine if the problem really _is_ exceptional. If it's not unusual that `health` is larger than `maxHealth` then I'd recommend against it.

Comment: yours is the only meaning full answer according to me

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I disagree. If caller calls your method with wrong arguments - how can you recover? And why should you recover at all? I think it's much better to inform the caller about violation

Comment: Though first of all, one should be clear whether it's an unrecoverable (or wrong) situation at all. This looks like a character in a typical roguelike, so let's say there's the potion of heroism, which indeed lets health exceed max_health -- but only for limited time. Now what should the program do if a player drinks such a potion? Count down the health until it reaches maximum? Silently set health to full? Abort with an assert message? The last one might be a serious immersion breaker.

Comment: @Damon: OP said that for his game "health obviously can't be higher than maxHealth". In case of different requirements - well, the idea is still the same: with assertions/exceptions we can enforce caller to obey the contract your API provides.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: A contract violation surely looks like an *exceptional* thing. I'd recommend reading [N3604](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3604.pdf) for a flexible approach to combining both the `assert` and the `throw` and letting the user decide at runtime one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

If you intended to set the health during the game you might want to consider something like this:

```
Warrior::Warrior(unsigned int health, unsigned int maxHealth) :
    m_maxHealth(maxHealth)
{
    setHealth(health);
}

void Warrior::setHealth(unsigned int health)
{
    m_health = std::min(health, m_maxHealth);
}
```

Comment: Read the comments on my earlier question, and pay extreme attention to Peter Wood's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529631/should-operations-like-less-than-0-be-handled-in-setter-or-outside-of-it

Comment: You can make the setter private, if that's is what Peter Wood implied - but it is good to do all the tests in one place. Let's say you want to create a "is_poisoned" and when you are the health packs are half as effective this could easily be done by adding it to the setter, in one place.

Comment: I heard my name (c: I think @Andrew's answer deals with this better by encapsulating the idea of a constrained, or capped value. zenpoy, I think the problem with setters is a red herring.

Answer (score 3):

There is a "better" way, depending on your definition of better. (And I'm guessing you mean "shorter" here)

```
Warrior::Warrior(unsigned int health, unsigned int maxHealth) :
    m_health(std::min(health, maxHealth)),
    m_maxHealth(maxHealth)
{
}
```

Comment: Which reminds me: There's this stupid Windows-specific header file that defines `max` and `min`, so it can potentially break `std::min` and `std::max`. If you ever face that issue, be sure to `#undef max` and `#undef min` somewhere.

Comment: You can also add `#define NOMINMAX` before including windows.h, or add `NOMINMAX` to the project definitions.

Answer (score 3):

This is really more of a question on the design of the interface than the actual implementation. Both of the implementations in your code are similar and implement a design with a *wide* interface that allows for *any* combination of arguments.

A different approach would be to use a *narrow* contract on your constructor, in which the behavior of the object is well defined only if the obvious constraint that `health < maxHealth` is true. In that case you would document the constructor as such and implement it:

```
Warrior::Warrior(unsigned int health, unsigned int maxHealth)
  : m_health(health), m_maxHealth(maxHealth)
{
   assert(health <= maxHealth);
}
```

Which in my opinion is a better design. There is no good reason to accept the wrong arguments to the constructor. By adding that `assert` there you can detect early in the development cycle when your type is used out of contract. This is specially important with functions that have multiple arguments of the same type, as it will help detect if by mistake you pass the arguments out of order. The use of a *wide* contract there would reduce the `maxHealth` to be the same as the current `health`, and at a later time you will have problems trying to figure out why the `Warrior` is weaker than you thought it should be... the *narrow* contract will tell you the arguments are out of order immediately.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
class RangeBoundValue
{
public:
    RangeBoundValue(const T _min, const T _max) : _min(_min), _max(_max) {}

    void setValue(T val)
    {
        if (val < _min) _value = _min;
        else if (val > _max) _value = _max;
        else _value = val;
    }

    T value() const {return _value;}

private:
    const T _min;
    const T _max;
    T       _value;
};
```

Use this helper class inside `Warrior`

```
class Warrior
{
...
private:
    RangeBoundValue<uint> _health;
};
```

Comment: This has got to be the worst answer I've ever seen. No offense, but who ever taught you should become a mailman or something.

Comment: I like the method actually. It would be better with a template. A RangedValue template has potential reusability imo

Comment: @PatrikLippojoki: I don't understand you concerns

Comment: This answer is more about the design, and not really helpful as an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I understood it a as a design question since OP has provided two workable methods

Comment: @Patrik This is a great answer. Andrew is expressing in code the constraints on the value.

Comment: @PeterWood It was totally different answer earlier on. Having a `Health`-class for one attribute in the whole program is simply a terrible idea, imo.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: agree, I just wanted to simplify the answer, but in that answer I also mentioned that template version is better

Answer (score 1):

I am quite surprised that people are suggesting to throw exceptions when an argument list to the constructor is supplied with health>max_health. For instance, say you have some resurrection implementation where all creatures are resurrected with a fixed amount of health up to their maximum health and in some cases this exceeds maximum health, to avoid coupling you don't want this method to have to store every object's maximum health, you could add methods to test for it before submitting these arguments to the constructors but again this complicates things. Max health is usually implemented as a ceiling on health and given that this is a simple constraint, uncoupled from anything else, it should be the warrior's responsibility to enforce its own constraints.